# Encode in webclient unexpected result

Tags: c#, encoding, google-translate

I try use webclient to translate word 'Banana' into rus

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigate("http://translate.google.ru/translate_a/t?client=x&text=Banana&hl=en&sl=en&tl=ru");
    }

    private void Navigate(String address)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();            
        client.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
        client.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
        string _stranslate = client.DownloadString(new Uri(address));
    }
```

And I want to see in "_stranslate "

> {"sentences":[{"trans":"Банан","orig":"Banana@","translit":"Banan @","src_translit":""}],"src":"en","server_time":0}

but got this

> {"sentences":[{"trans":"вБОБО","orig":"Banana@","translit":"Banan @","src_translit":""}],"src":"en","server_time":0}

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try checking the response headers, the content types tells you what encoding you should use.

`Content-Type => text/javascript; charset=KOI8-R`

So just add this line.

```
client.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(20866);
```

or

```
client.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("KOI8-R");
```

A complete list for encodings can be found in the documentation for the [Encoding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

Another way would be to just use [`System.Net.Mime.ContentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contenttype.aspx) to get the charset.
Like this:

```
byte[] data = client.DownloadData(url);
ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType]);
string _stranslate = Encoding.GetEncoding(contentType.CharSet).GetString(data);
```

Comment: I add this row
client.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("KOI8-R");
and all worked
Thank you.

Comment: @Likurg: I edited my answer again, might help if you have to deal with many different charsets.

Comment: That's odd @shriek. When I queried that URL, it returned it to me in UTF-8. I wonder if it returns different encoding to different countries. I've never even heard of KOI8-R. I think your second set of code dealing with the response headers is quite good. I didn't even know `WebClient` could return them. I was going to suggest `HttpWebRequest`. Upvoted.

Comment: @Chris Benard, i tried the site you posted for testing and it returns UTF-8, however when i try it from a test project i get KOI8-R. i also tried an online sniffer (http://web-sniffer.net/) and got the same result. As for `WebClient`, yes it can do almost everything you might want, and if there's anything that it can't you can always sub-class it. :)

Comment: thank you both for help. I update my code with System.Net.Mime.ContentType. Btw when my friend from USA tried to use my original code with @Chris Benard correction he said that all works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Add this before your `client.DownloadString()`:

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Your encoding is likely getting messed up when you read the string.

Using [this HTTP header viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) and putting in your URL, I see the following in the headers:

```
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: ru
```

Basically, you need to find out what encoding they are sending back and set your encoding to match.

It is very important to set the encoding **before** you call `DownloadString()`.

Comment: I try both variant, they didnt help

Comment: Btw i try to go on this url in Chrome, and I got file with normal text? After this, I use webbrowser control and when i navigate it to my url, standart download file dialog appear and in safe file was correct text.

Comment: Please post updated code @Likurg. I actually used your code and wrote it out to a file and it looked fine. If you look at [this HTTP Header viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) and put in your url, you will see the encoding is UTF-8, so the former should be working fine. You must put the encoding line **before** your `DownloadString()` call.

Comment: Adding client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 won't help you - google doesn't make sense for russian language (it uses Cyrillic). See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

IMHO better solution: add URI query parameter 
**oe=UTF-8**
and use UTF-8 everywhere

```
var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection
{
    {"client", "x"},
    {"text", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text)},
    {"hl", "en"},
    {"sl", fromLanguage},
    {"tl", toLanguage},
    {"ie", "UTF-8"},
    {"oe", "UTF-8"}
};

string htmlResult;
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    wc.QueryString = nameValueCollection;
    htmlResult = wc.DownloadString(GoogleAddress);
}
```