# C# encoding Shift-JIS vs. utf8 html agility pack

Tags: c#, html, encoding, html-agility-pack

i have a problem. My goal is to save some Text from a (Japanese Shift-JS encoded)html into a utf8 encoded text file.
But i don't really know how to encode the text.. The HtmlNode object is encoded in Shift-JS. But after i used the ToString() Method, the content is corrupted. 
My method so far looks like this:

```
public String getPage(String url)
    {
        String content = "";

        HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb(){AutoDetectEncoding = true}.Load(url);
        HtmlNode anchor = page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'article-def')]");

        if (anchor != null)
        {
            content = anchor.InnerHtml.ToString();
        }
        return content;
    }
```

I tried

```
Console.WriteLine(page.Encoding.EncodingName.ToString());
```

and got: Japanese Shift-JIS
But  converting the html into a String produces the error. I thought there should be a way, but since documentation for html-agility-pack is sparse and i couldn't really find a solution via google, i'm here too get some hints.

Comment: Please give an real-world url, maybe that could help

Comment: http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/politics/news/20130519-OYT1T00606.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `AutoDetectEncoding` doesn't really work like you'd expect it to. From what i found from looking at the source code of the AgilityPack, the property is only used when loading a local file from disk, not from an url.

So there's three options. One would be to just set the Encoding

```
OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis")
```

If you know the encoding will always be the same that's the easiest fix.

Or you could download the file locally and load it the same way you do now but instead of the url you'd pass the file path.

```
 using (var client=new WebClient())
 {
   client.DownloadFile(url, "20130519-OYT1T00606.htm");
 }
 var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb(){AutoDetectEncoding = true};
 var file = new FileInfo("20130519-OYT1T00606.htm");
 HtmlDocument page = htmlWeb.Load(file.FullName);
```

Or you can detect the encoding from your content like this:

```
byte[] pageBytes;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
  pageBytes = client.DownloadData(url);
}
HtmlDocument page = new HtmlDocument();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(pageBytes))
{
  page.Load(ms);
  var metaContentType = page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@http-equiv='Content-Type']").GetAttributeValue("content", "");
  var contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(metaContentType);
  ms.Position = 0;
  page.Load(ms, Encoding.GetEncoding(contentType.CharSet));
}
```

And finally, if the page you are querying returns the content-Type in the response you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043590/encode-in-webclient-unexpected-result/10043753#10043753) for how to get the encoding.

Your code would of course need a few more null checks than mine does. ;)

Comment: i tried to override the encoding since for my purpose it will always be this encoding. Worked fine. thx for the help!!

Comment: @user2399054: that's good to hear. don't forget to mark as answer if it solved your problem.